# I can't get Wujeeta to activate the skooma dealer quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I wanted to be the thane of Riften because it's my favourite city. I went to Wujeeta to give her a health potion and to activate the quest so I can become thane. But after I gave her the potion the quest would not show up. I tried waiting an hour (not in-game time) and I checked back, but there is again no option.

So I looked up this issue. Apparently, if you clear Cragslane cavern before you do the quest, it will bug the quest. It was advised to wait 3 in-game days for the bandits to respawn.  I waited, but they still didn't spawn.

I read that if you clear out the cavern 3 times it should be fixed. I have cleared it twice and I am still stuck. I also have tried `setstage freeformriften 12 10`, but still the problem wasn't resolved.

I also have 24 mods installed and running on my Skyrim game. Does this mean that I can not buy Honeyside and become the thane of Riften?

Comment: Are there any mods you suspect may be messing with this? Quest-related mods? Mods that change NPC behavior? If so, you could try temporarily disabling those and seeing if that helps. Make sure not to overwrite any of your saves, though! Disabling mods can lead to other issues.

Comment: [How do I buy the house in Riften?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37831/108003)

Comment: Are you playing on PC or console? PC users can set quest stages, which can help bypass quest bugs.

Comment: [Cannot get Wujeeta to tell me her dealer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/65044/108003), [How do I give Wujeeta a potion?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118579/how-do-i-give-wujeeta-a-potion)

Comment: @DCShannon I am playing on PC, but it doesn't matter now because I have solved the problem.

Comment: @DragongamerUK If you solved the problem, please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: FreeformRiftenThane 10 this will give you a marker to tell you to speak to the Jarl of Riften. ;)

Comment: If you read somewhere it will help to clear out the cavern three times, why did you only do it twice? :)

Answer (score 1):

After looking through multiple forums, I was unable to find anyone else who had this particular issue. That leads me to believe that this may be caused by one of the mods you have installed. Because of that, the easiest solution should be to use the following console command:

`setstage FreeformRiften20 10`

This command should add the skooma dealer quest (named "The Raid") to your journal, as it was supposed to when you gave the potion to Wujeeta.

Comment: I will try that the cavern has now reset for me so I should be able to do the quest and could it be the destroy the thieves guild mod or my ENB because they are the only mods I have got that are in Riften, if you know what I mean.

Comment: It's certainly not the ENB. It could also be a non-mod issue that's just rare. Whatever the case, let me know the command works for you :)

Comment: I solved it now I just typed in player.setstage freeformriftenthane 10 and the quest icon came up saying speak to the Jarl of Riften and then I had too buy Honeyside (which I think is haunted) and then come back to her after. I Then talked too my follower who is also my wife Mjoll, because when I moved in too Proudspire she would not say "you have quite a house. I'm thinking of setting up a small store here, you know sell odds and ends." Because she wouldn't say that when I was in Proudspire. She did say it in Honeyside though thankfully, well that's both bugs fixed. Thanks ☺

Comment: Do you know how too solve the cooking glitch because Mjoll wouldn't cook for me anymore.

Comment: I'm confused... So, you didn't end up using the command I suggested? Did you end up getting "The Raid" quest? As for your question about Mjoll, see [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41777/why-has-my-wife-stopped-cooking-food-for-me).

Comment: No I didn't get the raid quest i did type in the command you said and nothing happened.

Comment: That's absolutely bizarre. Well, I'm glad you were able to become Thane, but your question about Wujeeta has yet to be answered.

Comment: I did type it in right because I looked at how you type in the command correctly on the Unofficial Skyrim wiki and nothing happened. The only mods that change Riften and it's NPC's are true vision ENB, Bijin warmaidens (latest version), SKYUI again latest and destroy the thieves guild mod. Can anyone of these mods cause that issue?

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with the inner workings of those mods, so I can't say.

Comment: It doesn't matter now because I got to become thane thankfully. ☺ Also if you drop or sell the home cooked meals your wife makes you, she won't cook for you anymore and I have not done any of those things. But I only used them when I was on low health in battles. So I don't know how to solve it. As well as the Wujeeta one.

Comment: Rolled back edit made in January of this year that added a space between "FreeformRiften" and "20". The ID of the quest is "FreeformRiften20", and adding a space will result in the dev console command failing to execute properly.